# How do you get the parsed html of a page on the back end? (Within an Extension Using PHP)

Tags: plugin, extension

How do you get the parsed HTML of a page on the back end? (Within an Extension Using PHP) EE5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is looking for the answer:
If after your extension is called you can rebuild the template using the following code

```
function your_function($obj){
$template_group = "template_group_name"; \\(string)
$template = "template_name"; \\(string)
ee()->uri->page_query_string = $obj->entry('entry_id');\\assign your own entry_id (int)
ee()->load->library('template', NULL, 'TMPL');
ee()->TMPL->fetch_and_parse($template_group, $template, FALSE);
$rendered = ee()->TMPL->parse_globals(ee()->TMPL->final_template);
echo $rendered;
}
```

Of course you can display it or set values how ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you use this extension hook:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/global/template/index.html#template-post-parse

**Edit**

Here is an example of how this could work. Set up your extension and register it to run this method on the hook:

```
public function my_template_post_parse_function($template, $is_partial, $site_id)
{
    return str_replace("<my-tag>", "My-tag's output!", $template);
}
```

Read over the documentation on extension development for more information on how to use extensions and hooks:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html

Comment: How do I send the $this->final_template? Where does it come from? Example?

Comment: I added a simple example.

Comment: I must still be missing something. I have some learning to do.